# Can you use the PiCamera library with a camera that is isn’t the PiCamera like the picture?

Tags: picamera

!camera that I want to use(https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUJ2q.jpg)

I’m having some issues getting this camera to work, getting told that I need to check the SUNNY chip that as far as I know is only on the camera produced by the raspberry pi company...

Is PiCamera only usable with pi brand cameras?

Comment: Hi and welcome Sam! Could you please provide us with your camera's brand and model to help you better?

Comment: Furthermore, it will be easier to diagnose the problem if you quote the exact error message rather than saying `you need to check the SUNNY chip`.

Answer (score 0):

The [picamera's FAQ](https://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.13/faq.html) states it doesn't work with USB cameras, but I see yours is not a USB camera. However, the FAQ also says that:

> The picamera library relies on `libmmal` which is specific to the Pi’s camera module.

Comment: That camera seems to be one of the many Pi v1 camera clones. It should actually work with picamera if it's connected correctly